# Filter specific data and move it with header to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of 10 specific customers that I need excel to search and filter their numbers among hundred of customers in column D and when it finds them, based on their company code in column A, move the filtered range to a new sheet with a header (i want to move each customer with a header, not all of them under the same header) and name the news sheet same as the company code in column A

My Columns go from A to AC

What it looks like:

[image]

**I wonder how can i pull this successfully using VBA**

Adding Header to each customer:

[image]

Comment: Where do you 'have' those 10 customer numbers? So, do you like filtering by the list and save each filtered list per 'Company Code' which to be saved in a new sheet named as the respective Company code?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes Sir, Exactly, in column D I have hundreds of customer numbers, I need to filter column D for a specific 10 numbers for specific customers that i already have their number on hand then copy the filtered data to a new sheet based on the customer code in column A (with a header for each customer filtered rows) and name the sheet after the customer code.

Comment: I asked you **where** do you have them... If I would try a piece of code, what to use? An array, only showing how to be built?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes i will add them from a saved excel file with their numbers in it, or if it would be hard to so..i can just write them down.

Comment: It would be better if you would post something in an editable format. I consume more time to make a testing environment than making the code itself...

Comment: @FaneDuru i wish i can do that but StackOverflow doesn't allow files to be shared, tell me how it is needed and i will do it.

Comment: I already built a dummy sheet on my testing workbook....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It, basically, uses a dictionary to keep unique Company Codes, an array for the ten customers, a column array to faster load the dictionary:

```
Sub CopyFilteredCustomersByCompanyNames()
     Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, wsComp As Worksheet, dictC As Object
     Dim rngFilt As Range, arrCust() As Variant, arrFilt, i As Long
     
     arrCust = Array("108169651", "108169651", "108169430", "108169430", "108168704", "108169596") 'place here the 10 specific customers name
     Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'use here the workbook you need
     Set ws = ActiveSheet    'use here the necessary sheet (the one to be processed)
     
     If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
     
     Set rngFilt = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion: ' Debug.Print rngFilt.Address: Stop
     arrFilt = rngFilt.Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
     
     'extract the uneque Company Names:
     Set dictC = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
     For i = 2 To UBound(arrFilt)
        If arrFilt(i, 1) <> "" Then
                dictC(arrFilt(i, 1)) = dictC(arrFilt(i, 1)) + 1
        End If
     Next i
     
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'optimization to make code faster
     Dim keyC As Variant, rngF As Range, rngF1 As Range
     For Each keyC In dictC.Keys   'iterate between dictionary keys (A:A company names)
            rngFilt.AutoFilter 1, keyC                    'first filter by dict key
            rngFilt.AutoFilter 4, arrCust, xlFilterValues 'second by array of customers numbers
            
            Set wsComp = Nothing
            'insert the necessary sheets, name them (if not existing), clear if existing and copy the filtered range
            Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
              On Error Resume Next
                  Set wsComp = wb.Worksheets(keyC)
              On Error GoTo 0
              If Not wsComp Is Nothing Then
                    wsComp.Cells.ClearContents
                Else
                    Set wsComp = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=ws)
                    wsComp.Name = keyC
              End If
              rngFilt.Rows(1).Copy ' copy the headers columns width
              wsComp.Range("A1").Resize(, rngFilt.Rows(1).Columns.Count).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            
             On Error Resume Next
                Set rngF1 = Nothing
                Set rngF1 = rngFilt.Resize(rngFilt.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible):
                Set rngF = rngFilt.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
             On Error GoTo 0
             If Not rngF1 Is Nothing Then
                 rngF.Copy wsComp.Range("A1")
             Else
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                   wb.Worksheets(keyC).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
             End If
             ws.ShowAllData
          Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI
         Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
     Next keyC
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     
     MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

If something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: @Martin Did you load `arrCust` with your real customer numbers? Is the active sheet the one you want processing?

Comment: it filters my company codes correctly, also the customers that I need exactly but then it copies just the header to a new sheet and when I get back to the main sheet I find it filtering blank rows.

Comment: @Martin Do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed? If so and allow a connection I would like to see what's happening in your environment. The code works well on my computer.

Comment: @Martin Please, try the updated code. I also made a modification to make it more reliable.

Comment: This time, it just applies the filter on the main sheet, copy the header to new sheet and that's it,    in arr customers i put >> arrCust = Array("108169651", "107892100", "107892101", "107892102", "107892103", "107892108", "107892116", "107892122")

Comment: @Martin **Do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed?"**

Comment: Unfortunately, it's my work laptop so I don't have access, can I send you the excel file on your mail?

Comment: I found out that 1 customer number from column D may appear in 3 different company codes in column A, is that a problem?

Comment: @Martin Please, do it. The customer number may appear in different companies.

Comment: yes ! the customer number is repetitive and may appear in multiple different company codes, one customer number from column D may appear in US1 and US2

Comment: @Martin  I did not receive any mail... It is late in my country and if you will not send it soon, I will see it tomorrow...

Comment: Sent you the mail sir, so sorry for the delay. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @Martin  Talking about it, I thought you could see it in my profile... Anyhow, ivangu@yahoo.com

Comment: Yes sir, sent a mail to ivangu@yahoo.com with subject >> Filter specific data and move it with header to new sheet

Comment: @Martin Where from did you take the pseudo customer numbers? All codes from the sheet starts with '108` and what you placed in the array starts with '107`, except the first , which does not appear in the first iterated company (US3)... How the filter to find a match?

Comment: I've replied to your mail, kindly check your mail.

Comment: @Martin I am talking about the workbook received by email...

Comment: i've sent you another mail rn

Comment: Now i undertstand, please find this line with 108 starting codes,  arrCust = Array("108169651", "108169651", "108169430", "108169430", "108168704", "108169596")

Comment: @Martin This 'another' mail does  not contain any attachment. Only the text "I've sent you a real sheet with live data in this mail, the one in StackOverflow is dummy"...

Comment: I've sent another sheet to your mail.

Comment: @Martin I sent you back the initial workbook, using the correct array.

Comment: Brilliant ! can i add a header for each customer number within a company code? like US1 for example, it has 4 customer numbers with their rows, can i add header for each customer.

Comment: I sent back the second workbook, too. With the same code, but it must **not be placed in `ThisWorkbook` code module**! It must be placed in a **standard module**...

Comment: @Martin I cannot get you... Where to add "a header for each customer number"? Doesn't it have the general header? What do you really want? What do you mean by 'header' in this context?

Comment: I added a pic in the body of the post, by the end of the post, the header separates customers, each customer has its own header not a general header.

Comment: @Martin  It can be done, of course, but this is something different than your initial question! Our rules here do not involve such changes. Please, place another question and tag me (here). If I will be available, I will place an answer, if not, somebody else will do it.

Comment: I've made a new separate post rn, Thanks for your continuous guidance.

Comment: @Martin I could see your previous comment, deleted now, which was not correct. If you press the `edited xx mins ago` from your question you can see the editing history. At least, I can do it...

Comment: i didn't want to inflate the post with many comments so i deleted it and wrote a new one saying i made a new question as u told me, that's all

Comment: @Martin I updated the above answer, to make it not letting the added sheets where only the header will be present. I mean the ones different than S1, S2, S3 in sa sample workbook. I close my computer now. Good night!

Answer (score 1):

1. First create a tab by name **CCList** & enter all 10 company codes
   for which you have to generate the report.

[image]

2. Secondly Paste the data in the **Data** tab.
   [image]
3. Run this code.

In a new module

```
Sub GenerateReport()
Dim WsData As Worksheet, WsCCList As Worksheet
Dim FRow As Long, LRow As Long, FCol As Long, LCol As Long
Dim CCFrow As Long, CCLRow As Long, CCCol As Long, CCCounter As Long
Dim ValidationRng As Range, DataRng As Range, SrchString As String

Set WsData = Worksheets("Data")
Set WsCCList = Worksheets("CCList")

WsData.Activate
FRow = 1
FCol = 1
LRow = WsData.Cells(WsData.Rows.Count, FCol).End(xlUp).Row
LCol = WsData.Cells(FRow, WsData.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set DataRng = WsData.Range(Cells(FRow, FCol), Cells(LRow, LCol))

WsCCList.Activate
CCFrow = 2
CCCol = 1
CCLRow = WsCCList.Cells(WsCCList.Rows.Count, CCCol).End(xlUp).Row

For CCCounter = CCFrow To CCLRow
    SrchString = ""
    SrchString = WsCCList.Cells(CCCounter, CCCol)
    If SrchString = "" Then Exit Sub
    If WsData.AutoFilterMode = True Then WsData.AutoFilterMode = False
    DataRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=SrchString, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    On Error Resume Next
        Set ValidationRng = Nothing
        Set ValidationRng = WsData.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(DataRng.Rows.Count - 1, DataRng.Columns.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ValidationRng Is Nothing Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        Worksheets.Add After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = SrchString
        DataRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("a1").PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    
    If WsData.AutoFilterMode = True Then WsData.AutoFilterMode = False
Next CCCounter

WsCCList.Select
MsgBox "Task Completed"
End Sub
```